# Calling a function using Restangular in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the test function I have defined in my view's controller

```
scope.getItem = function () {
    var promise = Restangular.one('item').load();
    promise.then(function (result) {
        return 'foo';
    });
    return '';
};
```

In my view, I am trying to call this function, but I get an error saying that Restangular.one().load is not a function. What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `get` instead `load`, there is no `load` function in Restangular:

```
var promise = Restangular.one('item').get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call

```
scope.getItem = function () {
    var promise = Restangular.one('item').get();
    promise.then(function (result) {
        return 'foo';
    });
    return '';
};
```

Also make sure that you inject the Restangular Service into your controller.